# What is isometric game?

Tags: isometric, 2.5d

There is an understanding like isometric or 2.5D games. As I understand those are the same things. But I could not understand completely what is it. Is it about how the art for the game is drawn? I mean if art is drawn such that you see the game scene from the angle (visible from a top-down perspective or side view [from wiki]) and not perpendicular, is this isometric? Or there are some programming tricks that make game isometric, such as ability of the hero to move in 3 dimensions whereas it actually moves only in 2D like in old Nintendo games (Ninja Turtles or Double Dragon). Please explain this understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Isometric games are indead games viewed from above, in such a way that the x, y and z axis are exactly 120 degrees from eachother. So an isometric game is a game viewed in an isometric projection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection (this source is very reliable :P).

So as you have already guessed, it is about the way the game is drawn.

Comment: So if in the game 3D images have vanishing point then it is a perspective projection, and my game is 3D, but when there is not vanishing point, then the image is projected by isometric projection, hence, my game is isometric? I don't think so. Isometric game or real 3D game should have other characteristics too. For example in 3D game you should be able to see the same object from all sides in perspective projection. Whereas in isometric game, I guess, you should see only one projection.

Comment: For a game to be an isometric game, it has to be viewed from above with an angle, allowing you to see 3 sides of an object. You can't rotate smoothly (there are only 4 views). For examples of isometric games, think about the first sims, zoo tycoon and roller coaster tycoon

Comment: which 4 views you mean?

Comment: well, practicly it are 8 views, including the views from the 'bottom'. There are 8 directions you can look from to make al the axis 120 degrees from eachother. Of course you can zoom in, so instead of views, i should have said directions to look from I will see if i can add a picture to my answer

Comment: Here, the start of this video might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdxJQFXsxXQ